# ASP.NET - Insert HTML code to SQL

Tags: html, sql, asp.net, linq

For example, i have a `txtContent` textbox, then type this HTML code `<b>example</b>` to `txtContent` and submit that HTML code to a column in SQL using link, but it doesn't work, i have found something like disable validate and encode/decode

I have no idea how to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before saving to Html we should encode the Html tags, Then save it to Database to for text version we can use : nvarchar(max) or text or ntext column. 
for binary version we can use : varbinay(max) column.

Now To Encode text content :

```
string content = System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape(txtContent.Text);
```

then save "**content** " to Database.